# Google sheets adding an IF statement

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have the following formula in google sheets that returns the relevant cell value. I want to expand it for something else to to return a 1 if the cell is not blank, and 0 if it's blank:

=INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!g17")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!g17")="",0, 1)
```